# Getting client socket using beforeConnect function in sails.js

Tags: javascript, sails.js

Is possible to get the client socket that is attempting a connection to a server running sails.js, using the function beforeConnect found in config/sockets.js.

I've seen is used the parameter handshake, but I don't see where is the documentation of it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For get the socket.id before connection is created you, must type in config/sockets.js file this lines (getting cookie id sended by sails):

```
beforeConnect: function(handshake, cb) {

var id = '/#'+handshake.headers.cookie.split(';')[0].replace(/^io=/,'');

// `true` allows the connection
return cb(null, true);
},
```

Note: you must ensure that id starts with '/#' (which is the socket.id returned by afterDisconnect function).

Comment: Seems it works. I've noticed when the same user attempts several times to connect to the server, the id changes every time.